Is there a known correspondence between curved supersymmetric ambitwistor space and curved supermanifolds in four dimensions?
The nonlinear graviton construction in twistor theory gives a correspondence between anti-self-dual conformal manifolds and certain three dimensional complex manifolds, which generalizes the twistor correspondence to curved spaces.  I have seen some papers extending this to the non-self dual, or ambitwistor, case, such as "Non-self-dual Nonlinear Gravitons" by Yasskin and Isenberg or "The Penrose Transform for Curved Ambitwistor Space" by Eastwood.  I have not been able to find any papers that generalize this to curved supersymmetric ambitwistor space.  This case is interesting for a number of reasons, one being the work by Witten (1978) on "An Interpretation of Classical Yang-Mills Theory", which only deals with the flat case.  This could also be interesting for extending work on $N=4$ SYM into curved spaces.

I thought there was an answer yesterday
